# Monthly Snapshot using Date Dimension

Tags: sql, oracle

I've some columns that I need to bring to a consolidated table(fact). I've a change capture table which captures changes to record everyday which looks like this:

```
CHG_TABLE:
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+ 
|  Key   |     Start_Date    |      End_Date         |   Value   |Record_Type|
+--------+----- -------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+ 
| 1      |   5/25/2019  2.05 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |    800    | Insert    | 
| 1      |   5/25/2019  2.05 |      5/31/2019  11.12 |    800    | Update    | 
| 1      |   5/31/2019 11.12 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |    900    | Insert    | 
| 1      |   5/31/2019 11.12 |      6/15/2019  12.05 |    900    | Update    | 
| 1      |   6/15/2019 12.05 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |   1000    | Insert    | 
| 1      |   6/15/2019 12.05 |      6/25/2019  10.20 |   1000    | Update    | 
| 1      |   6/25/2019 10.20 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |    500    | Insert    | 
| 1      |   6/25/2019 10.20 |      6/30/2019  11.12 |    500    | Update    | 
| 1      |   6/30/2019 11.12 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |   3000    | Insert    | 
| 1      |   6/30/2019 11.12 |      7/15/2019  1.20  |   3000    | Update    | 
| 1      |   7/15/2019  1.20 |      12/31/9999 00.00 |   7000    | Insert    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

During first insert, End_Date is end of time. When new record with new Start_Date and Value is added to the source it's captured as new entry and previous record with same Key is updated with End_Date as Start_Date of new record.

```
DIM_DATE:
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|DateKey | Month_Start_Date  |   Month_End_Date      |
+--------+-----+-------------+-----------------------+
| 1      |   6/1/2019        |      6/30/2019        | 
| 2      |   7/1/2019        |      7/31/2019        |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I am struggling since I am using DATE dimension which has Month_Start_Date and Month_End_Date.

I want to create a monthly snapshot from this change table which would look like this:

```
RESULT:
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  Key   | Month_Start_Date  |   Month_End_Date      |Begin_Value|End_Value  |
+--------+-----+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      |   6/1/2019        |      6/30/2019        |   800     | 500       |
| 1      |   7/1/2019        |      7/31/2019        |   500     | 3000      |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

> Begin_Value : Max(End_Date) < Month_Start_Date
>
> End_Value   :  Max(End_Date) <= Month_End_Date

The Begin_Value should be most recent value from last month(which is not end of the time) and End_Value should be the most recent value based on Month_End_Date.

How to show above result?

Comment: Is a source record ever updated other than when the end_date of the previous record is updated following an insert?

Comment: I think your logic may be wrong.  I think you should look for End_Value = Max(Start_Date) <= Month_End_Date.  That is, for example, the end_value for July should be 7000, not 3000, because the value was updated on 7/15 -- that will be the value as of 7/31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rethink your logic a bit.

If `CHG_TABLE` has a 'update' record on July 15th and there is no later change, then that new value should be end value for July.

Assuming (big if) that's correct, then you should just ignore the `END_DATE` column altogether.  If you're able, drop it from your data model.  You don't need it.

Instead, create a descending index on `CHG_TABLE.START_DATE`, like so:

```
create index chg_table_n1 on chg_table (start_date desc);
```

Then, you should be able to create your snapshot fairly efficiently like this:

```
select ct.key, 
       dd.month_start_date, 
       dd.month_end_date, 
       ( SELECT value
         FROM   chg_table ct2 
         WHERE  ct2.key = ct.key 
         AND    ct2.start_date < dd.month_start_date
         ORDER BY ct2.start_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) first_value,
       max(ct.value) keep ( dense_rank last order by ct.start_date ) last_value
from   dim_date dd
INNER JOIN chg_table ct ON ct.start_date BETWEEN dd.month_start_date and dd.month_end_date
GROUP BY ct.key, dd.month_start_date, dd.month_end_date;
```

Hopefully you are on release 12.1 or later for the `FETCH FIRST` syntax.  Otherwise, you'll need to tweak that part to the pre-12.1 equivalent.

#### FULL EXAMPLE WITH TEST DATA

```
WITH chg_table ( key, start_date, end_date, value, record_type ) AS
( 
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('5/25/2019  2.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 800, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('5/25/2019  2.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('5/31/2019  11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 800, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('5/31/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 900, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('5/31/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('6/15/2019  12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 900, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/15/2019 12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 1000, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/15/2019 12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('6/25/2019  10.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 1000, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/25/2019 10.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 500, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/25/2019 10.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('6/30/2019  11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 500, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/30/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),3000, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('6/30/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('7/15/2019  1.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 3000, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,TO_DATE('7/15/2019  1.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),7000, 'Insert' FROM DUAL ),
dim_date ( datekey, month_start_date, month_end_date ) AS (
SELECT 1, DATE'2019-05-01', DATE'2019-06-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE'2019-06-01', DATE'2019-07-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE'2019-07-01', DATE'2019-08-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL )
select ct.key, 
       dd.month_start_date, 
       dd.month_end_date, 
       ( SELECT value
         FROM   chg_table ct2 
         WHERE  ct2.key = ct.key 
         AND    ct2.start_date < dd.month_start_date
         ORDER BY ct2.start_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) first_value,
       max(ct.value) keep ( dense_rank last order by ct.start_date ) last_value
from   dim_date dd
INNER JOIN chg_table ct ON ct.start_date BETWEEN dd.month_start_date and dd.month_end_date
GROUP BY ct.key, dd.month_start_date, dd.month_end_date;
```

> ```
> +-----+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
> | KEY | MONTH_START_DATE | MONTH_END_DATE | FIRST_VALUE | LAST_VALUE |
> +-----+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
> |   1 | 01-MAY-19        | 31-MAY-19      |             |        900 |
> |   1 | 01-JUN-19        | 30-JUN-19      |         900 |       3000 |
> |   1 | 01-JUL-19        | 31-JUL-19      |        3000 |       7000 |
> +-----+------------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
> ```

#### Update - version w/o MAX()..KEEP(), assuming the existence of `DIM_PERSON` table

```
select k.key, 
       dd.month_start_date, 
       dd.month_end_date, 
       ( SELECT value
         FROM   chg_table ct2 
         WHERE  ct2.key = k.key 
         AND    ct2.start_date < dd.month_start_date
         ORDER BY ct2.start_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) first_value,
       ( SELECT value
         FROM   chg_table ct2 
         WHERE  ct2.key = k.key 
         AND    ct2.start_date <= dd.month_end_date
         ORDER BY ct2.start_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) last_value
from   dim_date dd
CROSS JOIN  dim_person k
GROUP BY k.key, dd.month_start_date, dd.month_end_date;
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew McPeak. you;re right END_DATE won't be useful. But I think in your solution you only considered DATEKEY from DIM_DATE. I want this result to be on KEY for every MONTH.

Comment: OK, then you need a variation on the 1st approach I posted.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Would you be able to do this without KEEP function? I want to implement same solution in Snowflake Data warehouse but it doesn't have KEEP equivalent.

Comment: Yes, but it would require a different approach, and that approach would be more efficient if you had a table of unique values for `KEY`.  Do you have such a table?

Comment: I do have it. It's another dimension called DIM_PERSON with KEY as primary key.

Comment: Updated my answer based on DIM_PERSON table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196728/discussion-between-django-unchained-and-matthew-mcpeak).