# Can Not Group By on DATE from Timestamp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am unable to group by on date from a timestamp column in below query:

```
 
CHG_TABLE
+----+--------+----------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| Key|Seq_Num | Start_Date     | End_Date        | Value |Record_Type|
+----+--------+----------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| 1  | 1      | 5/25/2019 2.05 | 12/31/9999 00.00| 800   | Insert    |
| 1  | 1      | 5/25/2019 2.05 | 5/31/2019 11.12 | 800   | Update    |
| 1  | 2      | 5/31/2019 11.12| 12/31/9999 00.00| 900   | Insert    |
| 1  | 2      | 5/31/2019 11.12| 6/15/2019 12.05 | 900   | Update    |
| 1  | 3      | 6/15/2019 12.05| 12/31/9999 00.00| 1000  | Insert    |
| 1  | 3      | 6/15/2019 12.05| 6/25/2019 10.20 | 1000  | Update    |
+---+---------+----------------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
```

```
RESULT:

+-----+------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
| Key | Month_Start_Date | Month_End_Date |Begin_Value|End_Value |
+---- +------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
| 1   | 6/1/2019         | 6/30/2019      | 1700      | 1000     |
| 1   | 7/1/2019         | 7/31/2019      | 1000      | 1000     |
+-----+------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

> Begin_Value : Sum(Value) for Max(Start_Date) < Month_Start_Date -> Should pick up latest date from last month
>
> End_Value : Sum(Value) for Max(Start_Date) <= Month_End_Date -> Should pick up the latest date

```
SELECT k.key, 
       dd.month_start_date, 
       dd.month_end_date,
       gendata.value first_value,
       gendata.next_value last_value 
FROM    dim_date dd CROSS JOIN  dim_person k 
JOIN (SELECT ct.key, 
       dateadd('day',1,last_day(ct.start_date)) start_date , 
       SUM(ct.value), 
       lead(SUM(ct.value)) OVER(ORDER BY ct.start_date) next_value
FROM  (SELECT key,to_char(start_Date,'MM-YYYY') MMYYYY, max(start_Date) start_date
        FROM CHG_TABLE
        GROUP BY to_char(start_Date,'MM-YYYY'), key
       ) dt JOIN CHG_TABLE ct ON
        dt.start_date = ct.start_date AND 
        dt.key = ct.key
group by ct.key, to_char(start_Date,'MM-YYYY')
) gendata ON
    to_char(dd.month_end_date,'MM-YYYY') = to_char(to_char(start_Date,'MM-YYYY')) AND 
    k.key = gendata.key;
```

Error:

```
start_Date is not a valid group by expression
```

Related post: 
[Monthly Snapshot using Date Dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101141/monthly-snapshot-using-date-dimension/57117859?noredirect=1#comment100757135_57117859)

Comment: `dateadd` is not an Oracle function, and you have an extra comma, among other issues. But you haven't said what error you get when you try this. Explain what you are trying to do, with sample data and expected results. Please see [mre] and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: dateadd is Snowflake function. Added error

Comment: @AlexPoole does this help?

Comment: @Matthew McPeak This is related to your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101141/monthly-snapshot-using-date-dimension/57117859?noredirect=1#comment100757135_57117859

Comment: can you please also describe the logic for the result columns, so that we can also help you with the modifications in the query

Comment: At first glance `group by ct.key, to_char(start_Date,'MM-YYYY')` should be `group by ct.key, MMYYYY` to use the aliased column expression from the inner query. But I don't know or have access to Snowflake so can't really comment further, unless you do actually want an Oracle-only version.

Comment: @Tajinder Edited above

Comment: @AlexPoole That doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the logic can you please explain how values are 1700 and 1000.

Comment: SUM(VALUE) for KEY=1 and SEQ_NUM=1 + SUM(VALUE) for KEY=1 and SEQ_NUM=2 = 1700. It'll show up Begin Value for 6/1/2019 since its from previous month. 1000 is the latest value for KEY=1. If there was another SEQ_NUM in 6/1/2019 then it would be sum of SEQ_NUM=3 and SEQ_NUM=4. And 6/15/2019 is the latest value in June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

You can check below query

```
WITH chg_table ( key, seq_num,  start_date, end_date, value, record_type ) AS
( 
SELECT 1,1,TO_DATE('5/25/2019  2.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 800, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,TO_DATE('5/25/2019  2.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('5/31/2019  11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 800, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,TO_DATE('5/31/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 900, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,TO_DATE('5/31/2019 11.12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('6/15/2019  12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 900, 'Update' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,TO_DATE('6/15/2019 12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('12/31/9999 00.00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 1000, 'Insert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,TO_DATE('6/15/2019 12.05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'),TO_DATE('6/25/2019  10.20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24.MI'), 1000, 'Update' FROM DUAL
)
select key , new_start_date Month_Start_Date , new_end_date Month_End_Date , begin_value ,
nvl(lead(begin_value) over(order by new_start_date),begin_value) end_value
from
(
select key , new_start_date , new_end_date , sum(value) begin_value
from
(
select key, seq_num,  start_date
, value, record_type ,
trunc(add_months(start_date,1),'month') new_start_date , 
trunc(add_months(start_date,2),'month')-1 new_end_date 
from chg_table
where record_type = 'Insert'
)
group by key , new_start_date , new_end_date
)
order by new_start_date
;
```

Db Fiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c77a71afa82769b48f424e1c0fa1c0b6

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting an "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" and this is due to your use of the `TO_CHAR(timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY')` in the GROUP BY clause.

Adding the `TO_CHAR(timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY')` to the select side of your statement should resolve this and provide the results you are expecting.

````
a, b, dateadd('day',1,last_day(timestamp_col)) start_date,  TO_CHAR(timestamp_col,'DD-MM-YYYY'), ...```
````

Comment: You can group by something that is not in the select list; it's the other way around that throws that error. You've ignored the other column expressions that are *not* in the group-by, and the other syntax errors.